# About Subdifferential of matrix norm

Tags: matrices, convex-analysis, matrix-norms, subgradient, non-smooth-analysis

We have the definition of subdifferential of convex function $f : X \to R$ (where $X$ is complex Banach space) at a point $x \in X$ is set of linear function $v^*\in X^*$ such that $$f (y) − f (x) \geq Re \ v^∗(y−x)$$ and set of subdifferential is denoted by $\partial f(x)$ at point $x$. Then how to find $\partial\|A\|$ where A is $n\times n$ complex matrix. Since norm is convex function so can find $\partial\|A\|$.  Here norm of $A$ is operator norm.

Comment: Which norm are you considering?

Comment: Here norm of $A$ is operator norm

Comment: You need to use subdifferential calculus rules. Since calculating the subdifferential is hard in general, the way to go is to use the known atoms.